# When is the heat semigroup Gibbs?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory

Defining the Laplacian on a region $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions, under what conditions on the region (or other possible assumptions) is the semigroup it generates Gibbs, i.e. trace-class? For example, if $\Omega$ has finite volume, this is the case, and the book "Heat Kernels and Spectral Theory" by E. Brian Davies (where this question is inspired from) provides one other set of conditions (involving strongly regular regions). Are there other references that study this question?